# how to get profile images of other users using outlook rest image api

Tags: outlook-restapi

I was trying to build a small web application which has *outlook office 365* login.

So I was able to get the image of the logged-in user using below APIs:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('{user_id}')/photo
```

When I pass `user_id` of other users I am getting the below error.

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
  } 
}
```

But when I did the same thing in [Azure Sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/) everything went well. I was able to get the images of all the users.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. You should generally use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) rather than the Outlook REST API. While they functionally overlap, Microsoft Graph is the core Microsoft API going forward. Your calls (and auth token request) will be very similar:

   ```
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/photo/$value
   ```
2. When authenticating a user, the proper term to use is "Sign in with Microsoft". This is generally shown using this image:

   [image: Sign in with Microsoft Badge]

   You can find full details in the [Branding Guidelines for Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-branding-guidelines).

As for the specific error you've received here, you need to add the `User.ReadBasic.All` [permission scope](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get#permissions) to your authorization request. I suspect you're only asking for `User.Read` at the moment. This will only allow you to access the current user's information. You need additional permissions before you can access other user's in the tenant.

Comment: Yes It worked. My bad I didn't concentrate on scopes. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to specify width and height of the image in the api?

Comment: I want to get the compressed image of the actual image. I tried passing Height and Width properties to API call but It does not seem to be working.

Comment: You can get the various photo sizes from the `/me/photos/` endpoint (note the `s`). You can then request a given photo size by it's `id` (which is itself the size). For example: `/me/photos/48x48/$value`

Comment: what is $value what does it go there?

Comment: `$value` isn't a variable you pass, it tells Graph to return the image itself rather than just the metadata for the image.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur $value is confusing, why would they mess up with programming concepts in URL strings? Non-intuitive approach... It gives developers hard times. It just gives insight of a broken design at the first steps of trying to deal with it..